# Ошибка при написании urls

Tags: python, django

Помогите исправить ошибку N**oReverseMatch at /account/
Reverse for 'profile' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['account/(?P[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$']**

models

```
class Profile(AbstractUser):
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=160, null=True, blank=True)
    birthday = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('profile', args=[self.username])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

views

```
def profile(request, username):
    user = Profile.objects.get(username=username)
    return render(request, 'account/profile.html', {'user': user})
```

urls

```
path('<slug:username>/', views.profile, name='profile')
```

В шаблоне прописываю следующим образом **"{% url 'profile' %}">**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

судя по
`path('<slug:username>/', views.profile, name='profile')`
в шаблоне при обращении к `profile` нужно дополнительно указывать `slug`, в котором хранится username, по аналогии с тем, как Вы это делаете в `reverse`
`"{% url 'profile' user.usename %}">`